# vue-leaflet (leaflet) trying to reset style of the previous country

Tags: leaflet, vuejs3

I'm trying to reset the style of the previous clicked country.

Basically here's what happen:

1. the maps get a geojson with all countries shapes.
2. When I hover on a country it will change color and when I hover out it will go back to previous color.
3. When I click on a country it will change the color (permanent)
4. If I click on another country it will change the color too **but I would like to reset the previous clicked country to the starting style**

I think the problem might be related to the way I access the `$refs` because no matter what I can't use the `setStyle`. (Or maybe something else has to be done in order to achieve result)

Thanks a lot.

this is my (working) Map component:
**It misses the part where I try to achieve the previous clicked country style reset.**

```html
<template>
  <div class="map-wrap">
    <l-map
      ref="map"
      :options="mapOptions"
      :zoom="zoom"
      :minZoom="2.5"
      :zoomAnimation="true"
      :panInsideBounds="true"
      :maxBounds="[
        [90, 180],
        [-90, -180],
      ]"
      :maxBoundsViscosity="1.0"
      :maxZoom="2.4"
      :center="[47.41322, -1.219482]"
    >
      <l-tile-layer
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        layer-type="base"
        name="OpenStreetMap"
      ></l-tile-layer>

      <l-geo-json
        :visible="true"
        :geojson="geojson"
        :options="geojsonOpts"

        ref="arearef"
      />
    </l-map>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import "leaflet";

import {
  LMap,
  LTileLayer,
  LMarker,
  LPolygon,
  LGeoJson,
} from "@vue-leaflet/vue-leaflet";

export default {
  components: {
    LMap,
    LTileLayer,
    LMarker,
    LPolygon,
    LGeoJson,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      zoom: 2,
      geojson: null,
      mapOptions: {
        zoomSnap: 0.5,
        preferCanvas: true,
      },
      clicked: "",
    };
  },
  async created() {
    const response = await fetch("/dataset/countries.geojson");
    this.geojson = await response.json();
    console.log(this.geojson);
  },
  computed: {
    geojsonOpts() {
      return {
        onEachFeature: (feature, layer) => {
          // set each layer style
          layer.setStyle({
            weight: 1,
            color: "#999",
            dashArray: "",
            fillOpacity: 0.1,
          });
          let name = feature.properties.NAME;


          layer.on("click", () => {
            // reset to default style if the clicked layer is already active
            if (this.clicked === name) {
              layer.setStyle({
                weight: 1,
                color: "#999",
                dashArray: "",
                fillOpacity: 0.1,
              });
              return;
            }
            // change style to the clicked layer
            layer.setStyle({
              weight: 1,
              color: "#0f0",
              dashArray: "",
              fillOpacity: 0.1,
            });

            this.clicked = name;
          });

          layer.on("mouseover", () => {
            // do nothing if the layer is already active
            if (this.clicked === name) {
              return;
            }

            //change style on mouse over
            layer.setStyle({
              weight: 1,
              color: "#0f0",
              dashArray: "",
              fillOpacity: 0.1,
            });
          });

          layer.on("mouseout", () => {
            // do nothing if the layer is already active
            if (this.clicked === name) {
              return;
            }
            // reset to default style on mouse out
            layer.setStyle({
              weight: 1,
              color: "#999",
              dashArray: "",
              fillOpacity: 0.1,
            });
          });
        },
      };
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.map-wrap {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
</style>
```

and this is a small part of the geojson

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "name": "Countries",
  "crs": {
    "type": "name",
    "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" }
  },
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": { "NAME": "Fiji" },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              [180.0, -16.067132663642447],
              [180.0, -16.555216566639196],
              [179.364142661964138, -16.801354076946883],
              [178.725059362997115, -17.012041674368039],
              [178.596838595117134, -16.63915],
              [179.0966093629971, -16.433984277547403],
              [179.413509362997104, -16.379054277547404],
              [180.0, -16.067132663642447]
            ]
          ],
          [
            [
              [178.12557, -17.50481],
              [178.3736, -17.33992],
              [178.71806, -17.62846],
              [178.55271, -18.15059],
              [177.93266, -18.28799],
              [177.38146, -18.16432],
              [177.28504, -17.72465],
              [177.67087, -17.38114],
              [178.12557, -17.50481]
            ]
          ],
          [
            [
              [-179.793320109048636, -16.020882256741224],
              [-179.917369384765294, -16.501783135649397],
              [-180.0, -16.555216566639196],
              [-180.0, -16.067132663642447],
              [-179.793320109048636, -16.020882256741224]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
...
```

ps: sorry if I'm not posting a code sandbox but the map tiling was not properly working on it

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. Don`t forget add models to data (prev_feature, selected_feature). I use this lib: https://github.com/vue-leaflet/vue-leaflet/tree/master

```html
        onEachFeature: (feature, layer) => {
          // set each layer style
          layer.setStyle({
            weight: 3,
            color: "#3388ff",
            dashArray: "",
            fillOpacity: 0.2,
          });
          

          layer.on("click", () => {
            // reset to default style if the clicked layer is already active
            if (this.prev_feature) {
              if (this.prev_feature.feature.name !== layer.feature.name) {
                this.prev_feature.setStyle({
                  weight: 3,
                  color: "#3388ff",
                  dashArray: "",
                  fillOpacity: 0.2,
                });
                
            }
            }
            
            // change style to the clicked layer
            layer.setStyle({
              weight: 1,
              color: "red",
              dashArray: "",
              fillOpacity: 0.1,
            });
            this.selected_feature?.setStyle({
                    weight: 3,
                    color: "#3388ff",
                    dashArray: "",
                    fillOpacity: 0.2,
                  });
            this.selected_feature = layer
            this.prev_feature = layer
          });

          layer.on("mouseover", () => {
            // do nothing if the layer is already active
            console.log(this.selected_feature?.feature.name);
              if (this.prev_feature) {
                if (this.prev_feature?.feature.name !== layer.feature.name && 
                  this.selected_feature?.feature.name !== this.prev_feature?.feature.name) {
                    this.prev_feature.setStyle({
                    weight: 3,
                    color: "#3388ff",
                    dashArray: "",
                    fillOpacity: 0.2,
                  });
                }
              }
              //change style on mouse over
              if(this?.selected_feature?.feature.name != layer.feature.name){
                layer.setStyle({
                  weight: 1,
                  color: "green",
                  dashArray: "",
                  fillOpacity: 0.1,
                });
                
              }
              this.prev_feature = layer
            
          });

          layer.on("mouseout", () => {
            // reset to default style on mouse out
            if (this.selected_feature?.feature.name !== this.prev_feature?.feature.name) {
              this.prev_feature.setStyle({
              weight: 3,
              color: "#3388ff",
              dashArray: "",
              fillOpacity: 0.2,
            });
            }
          });
        },
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).